# Django: Create a random username

Tags: django

I'm using [this hack](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) to create a custom user model but I don't want when users have been signed in their emails to be displayed so I have another field called `display_name` where users get to choose what kind of name they want displayed. For this when a new users signs up I would like to generate a display name using his/her email with the part before @ symbol, this can be changed later if the user chooses to do so. My question is how would I go on to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
display_name = email.split('@')[0]
```